# Add text from QR Code next to generated PNG

Tags: c#, zxing, qr-code

I have made an application which generates me a QR Code in a PNG image, but now I have to insert the text from QR Code next to the QR Code image.

I don't have any experience using ZXing Library but I'm thinking that it may contain an option for this...

Example:
[image]

Code:

```
namespace QR_Code_with_WFA
{
    public void CreateQRImage(string inputData)
    {
        if (inputData.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data must not be empty.");
        }

        BarcodeWriter qrcoder = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H,
                Height = 250,
                Width = 250
            }
        };

        string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + inputData + ".png";

        Image image;
        String data = inputData;
        var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);
        image = new Bitmap(result);
        image.Save(tempFileName);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempFileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `ZXing.BarcodeWriter.Options` has property `PureBarcode`, which will put source text into generated image when set to `false`.

Unfortunately it has no effect when format of barcode is `BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE` (and it is by design).

But you can draw your text manually after you've generated barcode image:

```
var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
using(var format = new StringFormat(){Alignment = StringAlignment.Center})
{
    int margin = 5, textHeight = 20;

    var rect = new RectangleF(margin, result.Height - textHeight,
                              result.Width - 2 * margin, textHeight);

    g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush, rect, format);
}

result.Save(tempFileName);
```

Note you can select your own font size and fontfamily which will better suite your goals.

**Update:**

In the case you're trying to place text to the right from image - you have to "extend" to the right your generated image first, and then draw text:

```
var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);

int textWidth = 200, textHeight = 20;
// creating new bitmap having imcreased width
var img = new Bitmap(result.Width + textWidth, result.Height);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12))
using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
using (var bgBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
using (var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near })
{
    // filling background with white color
    g.FillRectangle(bgBrush, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
    // drawing your generated image over new one
    g.DrawImage(result, new Point(0,0));
    // drawing text
    g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush,  result.Width, (result.Height - textHeight) / 2, format);
}

img.Save(tempFileName);
```

Comment: It works! Can the text be positioned on the right of the image?

Comment: @PavelValeriu surely. Positioning of text is determined by rectangle you're drawing in (`rect`) and `format.Alignment` property.

Comment: Can you please help me on this too? I only managed to get the text in the bottom right corner, but I want it to be positioned on the same line with the image

Comment: @PavelValeriu not sure if I've understood you correctly. What do you mean by "positioned on the same line with the image"? Probably, some picture of your desired output will better clarify this than verbal description.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

When reading this page it shows the first 2 parameters (or 1 if using a point structure for it) are the position of the rectangle. Play with that to suit your goals.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndyKorneyev ! You saved me from spending a lot of time on this